# Alias a single Vue getter in mapGetters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex module with getters. I am using this module's getters in a vue component:

```
...
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('myCoolModule', ['isActive', 'someOtherGetter', 'yetAnotherGetter']),
}
...
```

I have other vuex modules that have an `isActive` getter, so I would like to alias it here. I am familiar with the object syntax, i.e.,

```
...
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('myCoolModule', { myCoolModuleIsActive: 'isActive', someOtherGetter: 'someOtherGetter', yetAnotherGetter: 'yetAnotherGetter' }),
}
...
```

However, I do not need to alias `'someOtherGetter'` or `'yetAnotherGetter'`, and the object syntax seems to require that I do just that.

Is there a syntax to use with mapGetters such that I can alias only one of the getters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about using it twice ?

```js
computed:
{
  ...mapGetters('myModule', {
    myCoolModuleIsActive: 'isActive',
  }),
  ...mapGetters('myModule', ['someOtherGetter', 'yetAnotherGetter']),
}
```

And why not namespacing your Vuex modules ? Thus name collisions like this will be avoided.

Comment: > And why not namespacing your Vuex modules --

I prefer to just use the module definition to namespace. In the `sampleStore` I would rather not prepend properties with `sampleStore`, which I find can be a little verbose/redundant.

Comment: Well, then perhaps you may find that using (global) constants for naming your Vuex getters/mutations/actions as recommended in the manual (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#using-constants-for-mutation-types) will help you to prevent name collisions.

Comment: AFAIK the docs only use global constants for mutations. Do you use them for actions as well?

Comment: Yes, I use constants for all the 3 - getters, mutations and actions. I use constants even in my event bus - for the event names.